# nothing shows up after using if statement in node red?

Tags: json, if-statement, node-red

I have the following example Node-RED node code, I am trying to get "hi".

I have managed to get value for age, but when I deploy the application, nothing shows up about the if statement.

```
var data= {
     "age" : "24",      

     "hometown" : {"country": "USA",
                   "City": "Missoula, MT"},                                                         
     "gender" : "male"
 };
node.send( {payload:data.hometown.country});
node.send( {payload:data.hometown.City});
node.send({payload:data});
var s =({payload:data.age});
node.send(s);
if (s == '24'){
    node.send("hi");
}
```

Here is the result

```
6/28/2016, 9:55:17 AM8ae7211a.e3f0b msg.payload : string [3] USA
6/28/2016, 9:55:17 AM8ae7211a.e3f0b msg.payload : string [12] Missoula, MT 
6/28/2016, 9:55:17 AM8ae7211a.e3f0b msg.payload : Object { "age": "24", "hometown": { "country": "USA", "City": "Missoula, MT" }, "gender": "male" } 
6/28/2016, 9:55:17 AM8ae7211a.e3f0b msg.payload : string [2] 24
```

I can see the value for data.hometown.country, city, and age, but my if statement is not working.

Comment: What do you mean with "node red"?

Comment: its visual editing tool developed by IBM, for IoT application and its based on node.js

Comment: this is simple .js, I just want to know you get value from if statement because the console doesnt give me error nor value.

Answer (score 0):

In a Node-RED node you can not send just a raw string `"hi"`, you need to wrap it in a message object with a payload field.

```
...
if (s == '24'){
    node.send({payload:"hi"});
}
...
```

Comment: var data= {
     "age" : '24',      
     
     "hometown" : {"country": "USA",
                   "City": "Missoula, MT"},                                                         
     "gender" : "male"
 };

node.send( {payload:data.hometown.country});
node.send( {payload:data.hometown.City});
node.send({payload:data});
var s =({payload:data.age});
node.send(s);
if (s == '24'){
    node.send({payload:"hi"});
}  After this code, I still get the same result.

Comment: Don't try and post code in comments, it just makes things hard to read

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
   var data= {
     "age" : 24,      

     "hometown" : {"country": "USA",
                   "City": "Missoula, MT"},                                                         
     "gender" : "male"
 };

    node.send( {payload:data.hometown.country});
    node.send( {payload:data.hometown.City});
    node.send({payload:data});
    var s =({payload:data.age});
    node.send(s);
    if (s.payload === 24){
        node.send({payload:"hi"});
    }
```